# How do I accept a command and a filename in the same input string in java?

Tags: java, string, arguments

Basically this is what my input will look like:

C:> ltf sample.txt

Then Shell v2.0(program) creates a sample.txt file in C drive.

I have explored the split() function but I have to validate my input from the commands stored in my array. So I need to "store" the file name in my array as well. I know this isn't plausible as the file names would vary. Basically what I am trying to ask is, how do I accept a command and a file name together? This is my current code just to give you an idea of what I am trying to do

```
package assignment311;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class assignment {

/*Data Members*/
    public static String[] myData;
    public static String CurrentPath;


/*Methods*/
public assignment()
{
        myData=new String[13];
        myData[0]="ls";
        myData[1]="ls -la";
        myData[2]="less";   
        myData[3]="gd";
        myData[4]="md";
        myData[5]="rnd";
        myData[6]="del";
        myData[7]="hd";
        myData[8]="uhd";
        myData[9]="ltf";
        myData[10]="nbc";
        myData[11]="gdb ";
        myData[12]="Tedit";

//initialise currentpath
CurrentPath="C:/";

}
public static void main(String[] args)
{



//initialise data by constructing an object of class

assignment obj=new assignment();
String userInput="";

do
{
//while
//get user input

System.out.print(" "+CurrentPath+"> ");
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
userInput=scan.nextLine();
String[] stringarray = userInput.split(" ");



/// boolean variable to display information about command validity
boolean isFound=false;

for(int j=0;j<myData.length;j++)
{
if(userInput.equals(myData[j]))
{
    isFound=true;
    if(stringarray[0].equals("ls"))
    {
        obj.Run_Ls();
    }

        if(stringarray[0].equals("gd"))
        {
            //ask user to enter a folder name
            System.out.println("enter a valid folder name");

            //get input

            String fdname=scan.nextLine();

            //get all folders name
            File myfile=new File(CurrentPath);
            String[] allfiles=myfile.list();

            // match user input with folder names
            boolean isdirthere=false;
            for(int k=0;k<allfiles.length;k++)
            {

                if(fdname.equals(allfiles[k]))
                {
                    CurrentPath=CurrentPath+"/"+allfiles[k];

                    isdirthere=true;
                }

            }
                    if(!isdirthere)
                    {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Folder Name");
                    }

            }
        if(userInput.equals("ltf"))
        {
            System.out.println("Enter valid file name");
            String filename=scan.nextLine();
            final Formatter x;
            try 
            {
                x = new Formatter(filename);
                System.out.println("File Created");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error man");
            }




         }
        if(userInput.equals("nbc"))
        {

        }
        }


}


if(!isFound)
{
System.out.println("Invalid Command");
}

// scan.close();
//end of while


}

while(!userInput.equals("exit"));

}

public void Run_Ls()
{
File obj=new File(CurrentPath);
String[] ls_result=obj.list();

for(int i=0;i<ls_result.length;i++)
{
System.out.println(ls_result[i]);
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing simple strings, store lists or arrays of strings:

```
String[][] myData = {
    {"ls"},
    {"ls", "-la"}
};
```

This way, you can preserve the structure of your commands (i.e. command name and all the arguments) without having to make guesses what a space in there might mean.

Answer (score 0):

You need command and filename on the same line. Instead of checking for userInput.equals, you could try using userInput.startsWith, this will return true when your input starts with a command which matches the array myData.

You may run into issues where there are two command which have the same starting alphabets like:

myData[0]="ls";
 myData[1]="ls -la";

You could change the above to:

```
myData[0]="ls -la";
myData[1]="ls ";
```

After you find a command which matches your list, you can do a substring where

```
String fileName = userInput.subString(myData[x].length).trim();
```

For a string "cmd ", the above operation will return only .
this will give you the flexibility of not worrying about the different file formats.
You may need to add some validation to the fileName variable though.